# What is the difference between "" and "_blank" in window.open()?

Tags: javascript

In the following two snippets of code...

```
function launchPage(url) {
var winOpenArgs="location=no,status=n,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes;"
appWindow=window.open(url, "", winOpenArgs);
};
```

...and...

```
function launchPage(url) {
var winOpenArgs="location=no,status=n,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes;"
appWindow=window.open(url, "_blank", winOpenArgs);
};
```

A new window is generated with the given website specified.  However, it appears that in the former, the window appears to be "persistent" - as if entering the URL in an *existing* window (or existing tab), while the latter appears to open a new *instance* of the window.

For example, one website will time out after several hours of inactivity.  If I close the window, and then re-launch the page with the former snippet of code, the window opens as if it never closed (the timeout message displays).  However, if I close the window, and re-launch the page with the latter snippet of code, it opens up as if I clicked a shortcut on the desktop.

Is this normal?  What about the former makes it behave that way?

Comment: The string is a unique title, but `_blank` is a reserved word **always** opening a new window / tab. If you use the same title again, it won't open a new window, it uses that with the same name.

Comment: But even if the window was closed, if I call the same window (again), it'll behave as if it was never closed?

Comment: I think so, because it has the same name. You can imagine the name is just a unique ID.